# Append to gzipped Tar-Archive

Tags: c++, compression, append, tar, zlib

I've written a program, generating a `tarball`, which gets compressed by `zlib`.
At regular intervals, the same program is supposed to add a new file to the tarball.

Per definition, the tarball needs `empty records` (512 Byte blocks) to work properly at it's end, which already shows my problem.

According to documentation `gzopen` is unable to open the file in `r+` mode, meaning I can't simply jump to the beginning of the empty records, append my file information and seal it again with empty records.

Right now, I'm at my wits end. Appending works fine with zlib, as long as the empty records are not involved, yet I need them to 'finalize' my compressed tarball.

Any ideas?

Ah yes, it would be nice if I could avoid decompressing the whole thing and/or parsing the entire tarball.

I'm also open for other (preferably simple) file formats I could implement instead of tar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion this is not possible with TAR conforming to standard strictly. I have read through `zlib`[[1]](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Gzip) manual and `GNU tar`[[2]](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html#SEC182) file specification. I did not find any information how appending to TAR can be implemented. So I am assuming it has to be done by over-writing the empty blocks.

So I assume, again, you can do it by using `gzseek()`. However, you  would need to know how large is the uncompressed archive (`size`) and set `offset` to `size-2*512`.
Note, that this might be cumbersome since "The whence parameter is defined as in lseek(2); the value SEEK_END is not supported."[1](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Gzip) and you can't open file for reading and writing at the same time, i.e. for introspect where the end blocks are.

**However**, it should be possible abusing TAR specs slightly. The `GNU tar`[[2]](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html#SEC182) docs mention something *funny*:

"
Each file archived is represented by a header block which describes the file, followed by zero or more blocks which give the contents of the file. At the end of the archive file there are two 512-byte blocks filled with binary zeros as an end-of-file marker. A reasonable system should write such end-of-file marker at the end of an archive, but must not assume that such a block exists when reading an archive. In particular GNU tar always issues a warning if it does not encounter it.
"

This means, you can deliberately not write those blocks. This is easy if you wrote the tarball compressor. Then you can use `zlib` in the normal append mode, remembering that the TAR decompressor must be aware of the *"broken"* TAR file.

[1]http://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Gzip 
[2]http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html#SEC182

Comment: +1 for the thorough answer, even though that's the very conclusion I came to myself. Thank you for approving my thought.

Comment: I do realize much of the answer is your conclusions. But I backed it up with docs. Also you said you **need** the final blocks and you are open to some other simple file format. The thing is you don't need them, even the GNU spec say it will result in "only" a warning. At the end you can say your alternative file format is TAR with out those block but requiring standards library `eof()` or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

This is two separate problems, both of which are solvable.

The first is how to append to a tar file.  All you need to do there is overwrite the final two zeroed 512-byte blocks with your file.  You would write the 512-byte tar header, your file rounded up to an integer number of 512-byte blocks, and then two 512-byte blocks filled with zeros to mark the new end of the tar file.

The second is how to frequently append to a gzip file.  The simplest approach is to write separate gzip streams and concatenate them.  Write the last two 512-byte zeroed blocks in a separate gzip stream, and remember where that starts.  Then overwrite that with a new gzip stream with the new tar entry, and then another gzip stream with the two end blocks.  This can be done by seeking back in the file with `lseek()` and then using `gzdopen()` to start writing from there.

That will work well, with good compression, for added files that are large (at a minimum several 10's of K).  If however you are adding very small files, simply concatenating small gzip streams will result in lousy compression, or worse, expansion.  You can do something more complicated to actually add small amounts of data to a single gzip stream so that the compression algorithm can make use of the preceding data for correlation and string matching.  For that, take a look at the approach in [gzlog.h](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/gzlog.h) and [gzlog.c](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/gzlog.c) in `examples/` in the [zlib](http://zlib.net/) distribution.

Here is an example of how to do the simple approach:

```
/* tapp.c -- Example of how to append to a tar.gz file with concatenated gzip
   streams. Placed in the public domain by Mark Adler, 16 Jan 2013. */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "zlib.h"

#define local static

/* Build an allocated string with the prefix string and the NULL-terminated
   sequence of words strings separated by spaces.  The caller should free the
   returned string when done with it. */
local char *build_cmd(char *prefix, char **words)
{
    size_t len;
    char **scan;
    char *str, *next;

    len = strlen(prefix) + 1;
    for (scan = words; *scan != NULL; scan++)
        len += strlen(*scan) + 1;
    str = malloc(len);                                  assert(str != NULL);
    next = stpcpy(str, prefix);
    for (scan = words; *scan != NULL; scan++) {
        *next++ = ' ';
        next = stpcpy(next, *scan);
    }
    return str;
}

/* Usage:

      tapp archive.tar.gz addthis.file andthisfile.too

   tapp will create a new archive.tar.gz file if it doesn't exist, or it will
   append the files to the existing archive.tar.gz.  tapp must have been used
   to create the archive in the first place.  If it did not, then tapp will
   exit with an error and leave the file unchanged.  Each use of tapp appends a
   new gzip stream whose compression cannot benefit from the files already in
   the archive.  As a result, tapp should not be used to append a small amount
   of data at a time, else the compression will be particularly poor.  Since
   this is just an instructive example, the error checking is done mostly with
   asserts.
 */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int tgz;
    off_t offset;
    char *cmd;
    FILE *pipe;
    gzFile gz;
    int page;
    size_t got;
    int ret;
    ssize_t raw;
    unsigned char buf[3][512];
    const unsigned char z1k[] =     /* gzip stream of 1024 zeros */
        {0x1f, 0x8b, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0x63, 0x60, 0x18, 5, 0xa3, 0x60,
         0x14, 0x8c, 0x54, 0, 0, 0x2e, 0xaf, 0xb5, 0xef, 0, 4, 0, 0};

    if (argc < 2)
        return 0;
    tgz = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0644);        assert(tgz != -1);
    offset = lseek(tgz, 0, SEEK_END);                   assert(offset == 0 || offset >= (off_t)sizeof(z1k));
    if (offset) {
        if (argc == 2) {
            close(tgz);
            return 0;
        }
        offset = lseek(tgz, -sizeof(z1k), SEEK_END);    assert(offset != -1);
        raw = read(tgz, buf, sizeof(z1k));              assert(raw == sizeof(z1k));
        if (memcmp(buf, z1k, sizeof(z1k)) != 0) {
            close(tgz);
            fprintf(stderr, "tapp abort: %s was not created by tapp\n", argv[1]);
            return 1;
        }
        offset = lseek(tgz, -sizeof(z1k), SEEK_END);    assert(offset != -1);
    }
    if (argc > 2) {
        gz = gzdopen(tgz, "wb");                        assert(gz != NULL);
        cmd = build_cmd("tar cf - -b 1", argv + 2);
        pipe = popen(cmd, "r");                         assert(pipe != NULL);
        free(cmd);
        got = fread(buf, 1, 1024, pipe);                assert(got == 1024);
        page = 2;
        while ((got = fread(buf[page], 1, 512, pipe)) == 512) {
            if (++page == 3)
                page = 0;
            ret = gzwrite(gz, buf[page], 512);          assert(ret == 512);
        }                                               assert(got == 0);
        ret = pclose(pipe);                             assert(ret != -1);
        ret = gzclose(gz);                              assert(ret == Z_OK);
        tgz = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);       assert(tgz != -1);
    }
    raw = write(tgz, z1k, sizeof(z1k));                 assert(raw == sizeof(z1k));
    close(tgz);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier and more efficient to remember where the tar stream ends and use `gzseek()` and `gzopen()` with append flag? I would assume that `zlib` would read relevant tree descriptions automatically then. At least you could leave, or rather push, the compress optimizations to zlib. I wonder if append continues the gzip stream or starts a new one. But I would assume they made it efficient. The effort seems the same - remember some position for `seek`. Also it seems like more effort than abusing TAR specs :)

Comment: You cannot use `gzseek()` to overwrite part of a gzip stream.  zlib does not support that.

Comment: However with regard to @luk32's suggestion, I cut off the terminating blocks from a tar file, and neither GNU tar nor BSD tar complained about it.  So the GNU tar documentation is incorrect or at least out of date about issuing a warning in that case.  I am using GNU tar 1.17 and BSD tar 2.8.3.

Comment: Sorry, but I have read as follows "gzseek [...] Sets the starting position for the next gzread or gzwrite on the given compressed file." My anserws are based on what I read in docs. I did not write code to check. I never said your anser would break TAR specs. Mine does. Yes, but I am saying 3rd time already. But gnu reference decompressor treats it as aa warning and says one should not depend on it.

Comment: You need to keep reading the documentation for like five more lines.  "If the file is opened for writing, only forward seeks are supported; gzseek then compresses a sequence of zeroes up to the new starting position."

Comment: You may want to read my comment -- in fact your solution does not result in any warnings.

Comment: I assure you I did! I am not that insolent. However, It is not written the starting position is the end of file. I thought when you open file for writing, you start from 0. Then subsequent call must result in a position greater than current. If it is different, than I am sorry and please corrent me and my understating of 'forward seeks'. Do they start from eof? I can try implementing a test but I will not have time for this until tomorrow. I also read your comments but you can check I cited documentation exactly, from less than 24h ago. So, as you say it might be outdated.

Comment: Then follow through with your logic and the documentation.  If when you open the file for writing it starts at zero offset, and you then seek forwards to write, then what does the documentation indicate will happen?

Comment: Dear Sir. I know the doc says it will fill stream with compressed zeros until the new starting position. So can you tell me what happens when I call gzseek() on a newly oppened file, with non-zero `pos`? will i get appended `pos` zeros to the end or at the beginning ? Or it will return an error. It is not clear to me. The same sense to me makes the following logic: whenever your new `pos` is greater than old original stream size then library compresses uses all-zero stream to fill in. I will check it.

Comment: When you open a file for reading or writing, using fopen or gzopen without an "a" (append) in the mode, reading or writing always starts at the beginning.  That's what you said: "I thought when you open file for writing, you start from 0."

Comment: Ok, so you open an existing gzip file with `gzopen()` with 'w' flag then use `gzseek()` with pos 1024*15. then `gzwrite()` what happens assuming the original stream was bigger than 15kilobytes? I will post a question and check it later. But I need some sleep and some time :) and we just clutter comments. Nothing in the docs says you can't open file with 'w' flag and use `gzseek()`, thus overwriting it.

Comment: If you `gzopen("foo.gz", "w")` and there was already a `foo.gz` there, it is overwritten.  It does not matter what was there before.  It's gone.

Comment: @MarkAdler Thank you very much for the suggestion. But let's assume we're leaving the tar termination out for the moment, would `gzopen` in `append` mode lead to good compression? Or would it be rather poor anyway? (Assuming we've got a fairly small file)

Comment: No difference at all in compression.  That is exactly what the code above does, except that it writes over and reappends the last 29 bytes.

Comment: Thank you @Mark for clearing it up to me. It was my lack of knowledge that you need to open with `w+` to perserve the contents of original file. I thought 'w' would suffice. And indeed the docs says `+` modes are not supported in zlib. Thank you again.